# $.ajax() function working in IE but not in Chrome and FF

Tags: jquery

I guess this question is not asked in this forum before, tried searching alot but none matched or worked for me. Below is the JSFiddle link of code:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh5Nv/)

Everything is working well in IE8 and IE9 but not in any other browsers. I tried looking for the problem in Chrome from which I got

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://v3.actisku.com/GetUserPostData?pid=Test-37&surv=1170. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

I tried searching for necessary solution i.e CORS but couldn't figure out the solution. I am side by side looking for the same.

EDIT:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<html><head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            var contents = $.ajax({
                url: 'http://v3.actisku.com/GetUserPostData?pid=Test-37',
                cache: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { surv: '1170'},
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            var test = contents;
            alert(test);
            test = test.replace(/\t/g, ';');
            alert(test);
            test = test.replace(/\n/g, 'break');
            alert(test);
            $('#contentArea').attr('value', test);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea id="contentArea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</body>
</html>​
```

Can we manually add headers so that the server feels like it is getting request from IE itself.

Regards,
icr

Comment: I used chrome on your fiddle and got data back.. no error of some sorts...

Comment: Its working for me in Chrome. You might need permissions on server.

Comment: me too, i don't got any problems when i checked it

Comment: dont execute the jsfiddle code directly, make a copy of html file which has javascript code along with it and open with chrome.

Answer (score 2):

ok as says there... "Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" **all AJAX/XHR requests are blocked by the server**. Please try to contact the server administrator about the server configuration

the IE uses a different way to send ajax request(so they were not blocked) because they are using `ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")` or `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` which the server maybe reads them differently as they are passed to the headers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I did know this solution. Unfortunately I don't have access to server config nor the admin. Is there any other way

Comment: well the thing we can do is (I don't know if it's possible) we can emulate the headers sent by IE for any ajax request so the server will not block our ajax request

Comment: I don't know how to, mind if you share a tut or link for the same, it would be of great help.

Comment: well as said on my last reply... i don't know if it's possible. sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code, to create Browser incompatibility. In fact they ware working fine in Firefox, and chrome. However, This seems unnecessary.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

As mentioned by Mahan, this looks to be like Server Configuration problem.

Comment: Please don't execute the code in JSfiddle itself make a copy of html file along with the javascript code. See my edited post.